# How to transform a Grayscale background SVG, to white or black colors

Tags: svg, css-filters

I have **Gray** SVG icons next to each Menu item (inherited from another project) and displaied as background.

I need to show them black or white but I don't how to achieve this.

As backgrounds I can't use `fill` css property. I tried with `filter:brightness(100)` to make them white but I loose anti-aliasing (and analogue with `filter:brightness(0)` to make them black).

`Mask` has still serious compatibility issues (e.g. Firefox does not allow external svg).

I tried also to import them as `data-uri` with LESS feature, but it was unuseful, so.... any suggestion?

Comment: Firefox does allow external SVG for masks and has done so for years (ever since 3.6 I think).

Comment: [partial support in Firefox refers to only support for inline SVG mask elements](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask) unfortunately

Comment: The site is misleading, you can do url(mask.svg#mask) and it will work in Firefox. What you can't currently do is a CSS mask i.e. the mask-image CSS property

Comment: Please, look at [this link](http://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images) (first section) with Firefox and Chrome, and see the differences

Comment: How is that inconsistent with my comment, mask-image doesn't work, external masks via an SVG file containing a mask mask: url(mask.svg#id-of-mask-element) do work?

Comment: Please provide minimal test case. Hard to help without code.